# Как настроить редирект с https на http с помощью .htaccess для одной папки сайта

Tags: .htaccess, apache, http, https, redirect

Здравствуйте. Есть два сайта на одном IP - `gmtravel.net` и `japonia.travel`. Необходимо настроить для одного с них (для japonia travel ) по умолчанию протокол http`,` но для второго оставить возможность соединения по `https`.

При этом файлы сайта  `japonia.travel`  расположены в `public_html` сайта `gmtravel.net` (как подкаталог) благодаря моим колллегам с Индии.

[image: скриншот]

Такая ситуация вызывает ошибку, когда при запросе `japonia.travel` через `https` отображается `gmtravel.net`  В настоящий момент установил перенаправление всего трафика по http через `.htaccess`

```
Redirect 301 /japonia.travel/ http://japonia.travel/

# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Но необходимо оставить возможность соединения по защищенному соединению для сайта с SSL сертификатом (можно не по умолчанию).

**Собственно - как направить  сайт japonia.travel только по http, учитывая что это физически подкаталог в основной директории двух сайтов на одном айпи, и как при этом задать исключение для сохранения защищенного соединения на gmtravel.net**

Вот такой вот вопрос :)

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашлось следующим образом (может кому пригодится) - в .htaccess основного и вложенного сайта, что в этом примере, добавлен следующий код :

```html
   
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^japonia\.travel [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```